# Algorithm to find the best profit in a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

If i have a for an example vector: vector prices {18, 8, 10, 16, 14}; Which is in another class. I have the class Trade:

```
class Trade {

protected:
    int buyTime;
    int sellTime;

public:
    Trade(const int buyTimeIn, const int sellTimeIn)
        : buyTime(buyTimeIn), sellTime(sellTimeIn) {
    }
```

What is the best way to make a function which get a random vector within the trade class and returns a Trade object. The function needs to find the best "profit" in the vector if you buy for an example at day 1 which is 8 and sell on day 3 which is 16. Also the sell cannot be before the buy. Each input in the vector represents the price in each day.

```
for (int s = 0; s <= prices.size(); ++s) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= vectorTotal; ++i) {
            allData.push_back(prices.at[s] - prices.at[vectorTotal - i]);
        }
    }

    void printVector(const vector<int>& allData){
        cout << "Vector: "; 

        for (unasigned int i = 0; i < allData.size(); i++) {
            cout << allData[i] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

This is my try to check the every number with its next ones but I cannot seem to figure out how to print them or even if i am on the right track.

Comment: Its not really clear what is the question. You want to know how to print the vector entries?

Comment: If selling short is allowed, you can go beyond the constraint that the sell cannot be before the buy. That's what short-selling does.

Comment: Seems similar to [how-to-get-the-highest-range-from-low-value-minus-high-value-within-an-array-of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860880/how-to-get-the-highest-range-from-low-value-minus-high-value-within-an-array-of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a vector of prices, if the sell has to come after the buy (no short-selling is allowed), then there's an O(n) algorithm that goes like this:

```
  double Best_profit(const vector<double>& price){
    int n=price.size(),i; double max_price=-1e+308,profit,max_profit=0;
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
      if(price[i]>max_price) max_price=price[i];
      profit=max_price-price[i];
      if(profit>max_profit) max_profit=profit;
    }
    return max_profit;
  }
```

The variable `max_price` finds the highest price after the current day `i`. The variable `profit` calculates the profit one would get if a commodity is bought on the current day and sold at that `max_price` (which has to come after Day `i`), and finally the `max_profit` finds the best profit one can make. It is crucial to work backwards. This algorithm has to do with dynamic programming.

Comment: There's a variation of this problem that is also practically interesting. Assuming all prices are positive, and that we have a fixed amount of money to invest, rather than a fixed amount of commodities to buy. Then we will be maximizing the return rate `r=max_price/price[i]-1`, rather than the price difference `max_price-price[i]`. The same algorithm would still work after this minor change. For your example data, the best transaction is the same (buy at 8 and sell at 16) and the return rate is 100%.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply really helpled